# Why does my custom 404 work but not my 403?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm working in a Symfony 2 project (version 2.1.11 to be precise).  I'm trying to customize the 403 page returned when using the Symfony firewall.  It correctly returns a 403 error but not using my custom page.

I am using the template override method by putting a file at app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error403.html.twig. I have an error404.html.twig page right next to it that works OK and is returned for non-existent URLs.  I've cleared my cache and I'm testing in the "prod" environment.

Anybody able to tell me where to go next?  I'm not sure why the 403 works but the 404 doesn't. If you have a custom 403 working at all, I'd also appreciate a comment on how you did it (maybe I can override that template elsewhere, etc.)

Comment: How does your error template look like?

Comment: It's super-simple to avoid any template-based problems:


     <html>
     <title>Get out!</title>
     <body>We don't take kindly to your kind here, stranger</body>
     </html>

Sorry for formatting - indenting each line four spaces doesn't seem to do it as I'd expect.

Comment: The `<title>` element must reside within the `<head>` element. I'd try it with `<html><head><title>Get out!</title></head><body>We don't take kindly to your kind here, stranger</body></html>`.

Comment: Thanks - good point.  I updated it to 

<html><head><title>Get out!</title></head>
<body>We don't take kindly to your kind here, stranger
</body></html>

Still doesn't do it but thanks for the input.

Comment: I think it may be due to environments. Can you try this bundle and see what happens? https://github.com/webfactory/exceptions-bundle

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer? Because IE doesn't give a damn about error pages it just shows its on.

Comment: You are most likely looking at the result of the Security component's exception listener and modifying the expected behavior. The firewall's ExceptionListener will grab a 403 AccessDenied exception and either redirect it to the login page (for those not logged in) or hand it off to a specific AccessDeinedHandlerInterface instance. This can be specified in your services.yml or in a security bundle you are using, so you may not be getting the opportunity to ever hit your customized error page.